# How to do if Jsp form fields are Empty or Null

Tags: jsp, struts2

Hi I am Developing JSP Form.If Jsp form fields are Empty or Null i wanted to print or update that blank fields as N/A. How can i do this?

```
<td><s:textfield name="surname" id="surname"  maxlength="50"
                 cssClass="TextBox" cssStyle="width:180px;"/></td>
<td><s:textfield name="forename" id="forename" maxlength="50"
                 cssClass="TextBox" cssStyle="width:180px;"/></td>
<td><s:textfield name="fullname" id="fullname" maxlength="100" 
                 cssClass="TextBox" cssStyle="width:180px;" /></td>
```

If User not entered forename then value should be update 'NA' in database.

Comment: Can you please explain a lil more and paste some code?

Comment: i would have to do in java script or somewhere?

Comment: Your form validation should happen in your js. You can take a look at http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Don't store some *custom* values that user didn't entered into the db. Instead change the logic where you are showing these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

You can do it in javascript client side in a function called by form's `onsubmit` event or by a submit button's `onclick` event:

```html
<form action="/foo" onsubmit="formatIt();">
    <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    formatIt = function(){
        var fn = document.getElementById("forename");
        if (fn.value === '') { 
            fn.value = "N/A"; 
        }

        alert ("I will send " + fn.value);
    }
</script>
```

But if you have different pages handling this variable, you must remember to apply the same behaviour in multiple places.

To avoid this, you can put this small logic directly in the getter of the variable:

```
public String getForename(){
    return (forename!=null && forename.length()>0) ? forename : "N/A";
}
```

The variable should be part of a bigger, shared object (like `Person.java`), not a single separate variable put in every action class (or you will have to remember to put this small logic in every getter...)